# Easier way to make if (test >= 0 && test <=3) for more ajax items

Tags: javascript, ajax

there is easier way to catch 4 items (variable test) and give 4 elements (variable i), if I continue with if () it works as I want but it will result in a lot of if ().

```
if(test >= 0 && test <=3) {
    if(i >= 0 && i <=3) {
        $(sample).appendTo($example);
    }
}

if(test >= 4 && test <=7) {
    if(i >= 4 && i <=7) {
        $(sample).appendTo($example);
    }
}

Example:
0  1  2  3 (variable i: 0 1 2 3)
4  5  6  7 (variable i: 4 5 6 7)
8  9  10 11 (variable i: 8 9 10 11)
12 13 14 15 (variable i: 12 13 14 15)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to need this simple check:

```js
    if (Math.floor(test/4) === Math.floor(i/4))
```

You can divide both the numbers by 4 to see if they have the same `quotient`. This will give you the behavior you desire (as suggested in OP).

See code snippet below:

```js
var inSameBlock = (test, i) =>  Math.floor(test/4) === Math.floor(i/4);


console.log(inSameBlock(1, 2));
console.log(inSameBlock(1, 5));
console.log(inSameBlock(5, 5));
console.log(inSameBlock(5, 7));
```

Comment: Sorry for limited info, I try to catch index from 0 to 29 and give first 4 elements (var i) for first 4 item (var test) and with test index = 4 give another 4 elements (var i). What you think about modulo? I mean using %?

Comment: I think quotient (and not remainder) is what you need as per what you mentioned in the description. You can remove all your if conditions and replace it with what I suggested. Let me know if it does not work for a certain value of variable `test` and variable `i`, and how you would like that to work for those values.
Please also expand and try out the embedded code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Using this approach, you just need to update the `vals` array if you want more values to be checked.

```js
var vals = [test,i]

if (vals.every(v => v >= 0 && v <= 3)) {
   $(sample).appendTo($example);
}
if (vals.every(v => v >= 4 && v <= 7)) {
   $(sample).appendTo($example);
}
```